# How do you make a custom post type invisible for subscribers

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, user-access

I am trying to make a custom post type invisible for the user role `subscriber`. How do I do that?

I tried the following, but that didn't seem to work. My post type is called `request`.

```
$role = get_role( 'subscriber );

$role->remove_cap( 'read' );
$role->remove_cap( 'read_request' );
$role->remove_cap( 'read_private_requests' );
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_request' );
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_requests' );
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_others_requests' );
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_published_requests' );
$role->remove_cap( 'publish_requests' );
$role->remove_cap( 'delete_others_requests' );
$role->remove_cap( 'delete_private_requests' );
$role->remove_cap( 'delete_published_requests' );
```

I thought this might do what I want, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

This is some part of my custom post type:

```
  register_post_type( 'antrag', array(

        'labels'              => array(
            ...
        ),
        'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'menu_position'       => 10,
//          'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ),
        'capability_type'     => array( 'request', 'requests' ),
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,

    )
);
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "make it invisible"? Invisible in wp-admin or invisible at all? And how about visitors that are not logged in?

Comment: Invisible at all, meaning backend and frontend. It should also be invisible to visitors that are not logged in, but I have that covered with a simple check, if the user is logged in. I would be grateful for a more elegant solution however.

Answer (score 0):

register_post_type() accepts a parameter capabilities in its arguments. See get_post_type_capabilities() for possible values.

you can add these settings in your code while registering the custom post type

```
'capabilities' => array(
'edit_post'          => 'update_core',
'read_post'          => 'update_core',
'delete_post'        => 'update_core',
'edit_posts'         => 'update_core',
'edit_others_posts'  => 'update_core',
'delete_posts'       => 'update_core',
'publish_posts'      => 'update_core',
'read_private_posts' => 'update_core'
```

),